# Data.Aeson import Key

Tags: haskell, aeson

I have the below code for parsing Int from an object. But unable to find the correct import for `Key`.

```
parseInt :: Object -> Key -> Parser Int
parseInt v field =
  asum
    [ v .: field,
      do
        s <- v .: field
        case readMaybe s :: Maybe Int of
          Nothing -> fail "not a number"
          Just x -> return x
    ]
```

I have tried

```
import Data.Aeson
```

and

```
import Data.Aeson.Types
```

But get the error

```
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Key’
    A data constructor of that name is in scope; did you mean DataKinds?
```

What should be the correct import for `Key` in my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're writing code targeting `aeson` 2.x, but that you have `aeson` 1.x installed. Either upgrade (recommended), or use `Text` in place of `Key` there.

Comment: I have Aeson 2.0.3.0 . But making it Text works. I will dig deeper into the versioning. Maybe it's the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: @ChopTRAN Are you sure that's the version that's actually in use? You might have multiple versions and be using the old one. Also, if you go into GHCi and do those imports, what does `:t (.:)` say?

Comment: `:t (.:)` confirmed my `stack` is using version 1x . Cheers.